# Javascript in application.js for a field in the _form partial fails to work for the edit action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have some javascript to control how some fields in the _form partial work based on the radio buttons clicked. Everything works well when I am entering a new record (new) action, but during editing, where the same _form partial is rendered, the javascript does not seem to have any effect.

Why the strange behaviour?

Here is the code sample:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="staff[optquestion]"]').on('change', function() {
        $('select[name="staff[Redesignation]"]').attr('disabled', this.value 
!= "true")
    });
});


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="staff[staffpresent]"]').on('change', function() {
        $('select[name="staff[absent_reason]"]').attr('disabled', this.value 
!= "false")
    });
});
```

I have also noted that the javascript does not seem to work when I load the same page on my phone.

Comment: Any code sample?

Comment: well, a code sample will be needed to debug your issue..

Comment: Edit your question to add code sample in it to make it more readable

Comment: Thank you guys, I have added the code sample.

Comment: Try to move the js codes to a separate `custom.js` file and require that file in your `application.js`. It'll solve the issue + it's clean code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `turbolinks` installed then it must not work, see the [`turbolinks`](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks) documentation, write code like this

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){
    $('input[name="staff[optquestion]"]').on('change', function() {
        $('select[name="staff[Redesignation]"]').attr('disabled', this.value 
!= "true")
    });
});
```

added `turbolinks:load`